# What type of loop to use with this pseudo code

Tags: python, loops

This is for a python project I'm working on. I'm still learning the language, but I have hit a stump here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my pseudo code:

```
variable1 = (returned function() value)
listItem = []

<start loop>
If value of variable1 IS NOT in listItem:
listItem.append(assign value from variable1)

else:
go back to start of loop

print listItem(all items)
```

I am confused if its best to use a for, while, or if statement here. I have tried with all three, but I get various errors. I am not seeing something...

Comment: What type of errors have you gotten?

Comment: Your loop seems incomplete. There is something else that you need to do inside the loop. Otherwise all you need is an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert a list to a unique list:

```
>>> results = function()
>>> unique = []
>>> for result in results:
...     if result not in unique:
...         unique.append(result)
```

`set` is good for uniqueness, and you can convert it to a `list` easily:

```
>>> unique = list(set(results))
```

However, this won't keep the order of the original results.

Python doesn't have an ordered set, but it does have an ordered dictionary, which you can abuse by using it's keys as an ordered set:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> ordered_unique = OrderedDict((key, key) for key in results).keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently all you need is the if statement, you don't need the loop or the else statement.
If I understand you correctly, you want to search listItem for ONE variable (variable1), and if it doesn't contain that variable, you want to append it to the list. However, it seems like your question is missing something. Perhaps you are trying to search listItem for multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight everyone. I have figured it out. I needed to use a while loop for this task. Here is my solution.

```
variable0 = <null value>
listItem = [empty list]

variable1 = 0  (required for while loop expression)
while variable1 is less than 0:
     variable0 = (returned random function() value)
     if variable0 is not in listItem:
          Append variable0 value to listItem
increase value of variable1 by 1

print contents of listItem
```

Thanks again for all of your help.